# EntityFramework Parameter value is out of range

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Despite of all already read answers, cannot deal with **Decimal** and EF.
I've a SQLServer 2012 table (*Traffico*) who defines this field:

```
[traffico_out] [decimal](30, 10) NULL
```

If I test with this simple query:

```
UPDATE dbo.Traffico
SET traffico_out=55534448359.141929
WHERE id=10;
```

All works fine and the decimal value is stored.

I've to deploy an ASP.NET MVC 4 application using Entity Framework 6, **Database First** approach.
I've generated the model starting from existing table.

**Context**

```
public partial class PeeringEntities : DbContext
{

  public PeeringEntities()
    : base("name=PeeringEntities")
  {
  }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
  }

  public virtual DbSet<Traffico> Traffico { get; set; }

}
```

**Table entity**

```
public partial class Traffico
{
  public int id { get; private set; }
  public Nullable<decimal> traffico_out { get; set; }
}
```

**EDMX**

```
<EntityType Name="Traffico">
  <Property Name="id" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="traffico_out" Type="decimal" Precision="30" Scale="10" />
</EntityType>
```

All the code ablove has been auto-generated.

**Exception**

When I attempt to add a new record to '*Traffico*' table, I get an out of range error. In my Controller (where *db* is DbContext):

```
Traffico _new_item = new Traffico();
_new_item.traffico_out = 5283148511.91876M;
db.Traffico.Add(_new_item);
db.SaveChanges();
```

At SaveChanges time I got a DbUpdateException:

```
InnerException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
InnerException -> InnerException: {"Parameter value '5283148511,91876' is out of range."}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Looking at my output directory I've found three files that are generated from my EDMX:

1. .csdl
2. .msl
3. .ssdl

Despite of edmx precision and scale, I've found in the .ssdl:

```
<Property Name="traffico_out" Type="decimal" Precision="12" Scale="5" />
```

Now I'm really confused: how can I change this?

Comment: Your error message has `'5283148511,91876'` (comma as the separator) but your test was with `SET traffico_out=55534448359.141929` (dot as separator) Is that just a typo?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: thank you for give a look. I don't known, may be this depends on local settings (in Italy the comma is the decimal separator). My code is exactly what you read.

Comment: Try type double or set a maxlenght/mask in the input to be the same as in db [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801215/parameter-is-out-of-range-on-db-savechanges-in-ef?rq=1)

Comment: thank you link but change traffico_out from decimal to double generates a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

The value `55534448359.141929` is larger than can be stored in a `Decimal(12,5)`.

The 12 (precision) being the maximum digits allowed in the number, thus 999999999999
and scale being the maximum number of digits after the decimal point. So, 9999999.99999 is the highest decimal you can store in a  decimal(12,5)

Comment: Thank you jvanrhyn but 'id' field is computed by the server. traffico_out field is what I've to set.